# How can I map each json file to individual collection in comsosDB's database?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am using copy activity to perform backup and restore activities for cosmosDB. I was able to backup multiple collections from database as individual json files. But when I restore I was not able to map those multiple files to individual collections back in comosDB databases.

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: it is indeed i am communicating with azure team as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The collection name need to be defined when you use cosmos db sql api connector as source dataset.

[image]

So you could define the file name in the blob storage output destination as the name of the collection.

[image]

When you restore the data back to collection,you could know which collection that this json file maps to. Then execute multiple copy activities one by one to restored data individually.

BTW,another cosmos db [migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) could implement same requirements,you could get know about it.

Comment: But what iif, if i don't know  the no.of  collection exists and their names